# Application screen goes blank and shows error (Type Error: Assignment to constant)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, access-token

Anyone any ideas why this shows a blank screen on my mobile application but works on the web?

```
const [access_token, setAccessToken] = useState();
const [refresh_token, setRefreshToken] = useState();


  if (access_token) {
    localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', JSON.stringify(refresh_token));
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', JSON.stringify(access_token));
    // localStorage.setItem('expires_in', JSON.stringify(expires_in));
  } else {
    access_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    refresh_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
You should use setAccessToken and setRefreshToken for assignmentn not 
access_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
refresh_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'));

setAccessToken(localStorage.getItem('access_token'))
setRefreshToken(localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'))
```

Comment: like this -     setAccessToken(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token')));

Comment: yes, should work

Comment: problem is my access token is being set by a login button on another page and being passed back as a prop. Unless the access_token is there the application is still blank? If I manually put it in in debugger it works